# What graphics library to use for graphics with Cython?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, emulation, cython

I'd like to create a chip-8 emulator with Cython, but I'm having trouble finding an openGL graphics library to use. What are my best options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kivy](http://kivy.org/) is based on Cython (for internals) and OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://www.ogre3d.org/

A python wrapper for the same is here: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/PyOgre